# Samsung Galaxy Tab E SM-T560 bricked

Tags: samsung, rooting, 4.4-kitkat, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab

Recently, I tried to root my **Samsung Galaxy Tab E T-560** and I was unsuccessful. This is the first device I tried to root so I do not have much knowledge about this topic. I decided to root the tablet because the tablet stuck on `Android 4.4` and I cannot launch many apps from the Play store.

I followed one tutorial which was specifically for this tablet. First I installed `USB Drivers` on my notebook, installed software `Odin3 v3.14.4`, and downloaded `Samsung Auto-Root pack` and unpacked files.

On the tablet, I opened `Settings`, enabled Developer settings, and turned on `OEM LOCK`. Then I opened the Odin software and with the `AP` button, I selected a file with .md5 extension (`CF-Auto-Root-s5neolte-s5neoltex-smg903f.tar.md5`). Next, I turned my tablet into `download mode` and connect it to my notebook with a USB cable. Last, I pressed the `Start` button, and after some time rooting failed.

Now my device is bricked and it stuck on the screen with the message:

> "Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in
> Kies & try again."

Can someone please tell me if I can unbrick my device and what I did wrong? I suppose that I chose the wrong `.md5` file but unfortunately, I believed what the tutorial says.

Comment: Why have you installed a firmware for the smg903f (Galaxy S5) on a Tab E T-560? You need an exactly matching firmware for each device!

Comment: It is true, I made a mistake. Do you maybe know if there is some option to unbrick the tablet? @Robert

Comment: The chance I see is to get back into download mode and install a correct firmware.